# Перенос длинных строк в ячейке таблице

Tags: html, css

Доброго времени суток! У меня возникла проблема небольшая. Когда в ячейке таблицы выводится большая длинная строка (например ссылка) то она растягивает всю таблицу, нарушая всю верстку таблицы. Вот к примеру в Opere корректно выводятся ссылки, перенос идет если строка выходит за границы ячейки th:

[image]

А вот как выводится к примеру в IE:

[image]

Второй вариант конечно неприемлиемый. Пробовал вот так задавать для
div (который в ячейках находится):

```
style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap"
```

И не помогает, а к тому же нарушает верстку и в опере.

Потом пробовал вот так для div-контейнера прописать:

```
div1 {
 white-space: pre-wrap; /* css-3 */
 white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla, начиная с 1999 года */
 white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4-6 */
 white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */
 word-wrap: break-word; /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
 }
```

Тоже не хочет работать... Подскажите как решить проблему?

Вот ссылка теперешней верстки таблицы в сервисе [Edit Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DBY7Z/1/)

Некорректно работает в хроме, ie.

Comment: Нет возможности задать явную ширину для div блока? или столбца таблицы?

Comment: Для столбца пробовал задавать фиксированную width, но ситуация не менялась. Я не верстальщик, а программист, потому мне это кажется серьезной проблемой. Длинные строки заставляют разъезжаться ячейки.

Comment: что такое `megasmiled` ???? нет такого атрибута в html

Comment: Да это потому что я выдрал код html из отладчика opera. В реальном коде у меня такого атрибута нет. Сам не пойму откуда он появился там. Вот поправил без этих странных тегов). http://jsfiddle.net/DBY7Z/4/

Comment: это или расширение какое-то или вирус по всей видимости

Comment: Вирус внедренный в Opera?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

css:

```
word-break: break-all;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/DBY7Z/2/

пожалуйста, **выделяйте проблему лучше**, ваш код для примера должен выглядеть примерно так:
http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/DBY7Z/3/

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Только я не понял почему в этом примере нигде нет http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/DBY7Z/2/ куска кода word-break: break-all? Что вы изменили там, что все работает?

Comment: он там есть: в секции `.simple-little-table tr td ` поэтому я вам и говорю - лучше выделяйте проблему. это всем будет удобнее и отвечающему и спрашивающему, и тем кто с поиска попадет.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Хорошо учту на будущее, буду локализовывать проблему. Отмечаю ответ как верным и палец вверх жму), @eicto