# ограничение ширины столбца сгенерированной таблицы

Tags: javascript, html, css

у меня есть 2 массива, которые каждый из которых является осями таблицы(заголовки по оси x и у). по ним скриптом генерируется таблица с необходимой иерархией(которая забита  в массивах).
проблема возникает в том, что таблица расширяется и выходит за пределы поля( табица находится в div , у которого ограниченная ширина). как решить данную проблему?
таблица
`

```
        </thead>
        <tbody id="modal_tbody">
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>`
```

часть скрипта(отвечает за генерацию таблицы):

```
var s = get_child($a_axis)
            var s2 = get_child($y_axis)
            var thead=document.getElementById('modal_thead')
            var tbody=document.getElementById('modal_tbody')
            var str = 0
            var str2=0

        for (var i=0;i<s.length;i++){
            if (str<s[i].length){
            str=s[i].length
            }

        }
        for (var i=0;i<s2.length;i++){
            if (str2<s2[i].length){
            str2=s2[i].length
            }

        }
        for (var c=0; c<str;c++){
            var tr=document.createElement('tr')
            thead.appendChild(tr)
            var q=1
            if (c==0){
                var td=document.createElement('td')
                td.setAttribute('colspan',str2)
                td.setAttribute('rowspan',str)
                td.setAttribute('align',"center")
                thead.lastChild.appendChild(td)
            }
            for (var i=0;i<s.length;i++){
                if (c<s[i].length){
                    if ((i!=0)&&(s[i][c]==s[i-1][c])){
                        q++
                        thead.lastChild.lastChild.setAttribute('colspan',q)
                    }
                    else{
                        q=1
                        var td = document.createElement('td')
                        if (c+1==s[i].length){
                            td.setAttribute('rowspan',str-c)
                        }
                        td.innerHTML = s[i][c]
                        td.setAttribute('align',"center")
                        thead.lastChild.appendChild(td)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        var ss=0
        var fff=0
        for (var i=0;i<s2.length;i++){
            var tr=document.createElement('tr')
            tbody.appendChild(tr)
            var q=1
            for (var c=0;c<str2;c++){
                if (c<s2[i].length){
                    if (i==0){
                        var td = document.createElement('td')
                        td.innerHTML = s2[i][c]
                        td.setAttribute('align',"center")
                        tbody.lastChild.appendChild(td)
                    }
                    else{
                        if ((c<s2[i-1].length)&&(s2[i][c]==s2[i-1][c])){
                            var el = s2[i][c].length
                            for (var trs=tbody.children.length-2;trs>=0;trs--){
                                if (s2[trs][c]==s2[i][c]){
                                    var prov=0
                                    for (var rt=0;rt<tbody.children[trs].children.length;rt++){
                                        if (s2[i][c]==tbody.children[trs].children[rt].innerHTML){
                                            var q=tbody.children[trs].children[rt].getAttribute('rowspan')
                                            if (!q){
                                                q=2
                                            }
                                            else{
                                                q++
                                            }

                                            prov=1
                                            tbody.children[trs].children[rt].setAttribute('rowspan',q)
                                            break
                                        }
                                    }
                                    if (prov==1){
                                        break
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            var td = document.createElement('td')
                            if (c+1==s2[i-1].length){
                                qq=i
                            }
                            if (c+1==s2[i].length){
                                td.setAttribute('colspan',str2-c)
                                qq=i
                            }
                            td.innerHTML = s2[i][c]
                            td.setAttribute('align',"center")
                            tbody.lastChild.appendChild(td)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    })
```

Comment: А код показать трудно? Добавь код!!!!

Comment: @Air добавил часть кода   .

Comment: ты извини, но это не часть, а огрызок кода...

Comment: @Air , а чего тебе не хватает?
могу  добавить того, что тебе надо

Comment: и тем более, что твоя проблема css

Comment: css пустой, метку css я поставил внизу

Comment: пример должен быть минимальны самодостаточны и воспроизводимый...

Comment: да и все аттрибуты (почти ) задаю в скрипте

Comment: так чего не хватает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нашел я ответ на данный вопрос(вот тут):[Перенос длинных строк в ячейке таблице](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/280619/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5)

если кратко , то в тег таблицы надо добавить к атрибуту `style` СЛЕДУЮЩИЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЯ `width:100%;word-break: break-all;table-layout: fixed`, как итог, у нас фиксированная ширина столбца и значения не обрезаются а переносятся